# ¿Cómo filtrar filas que solo contienen un valor igual a 1?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Tengo un DataFrame con los siguientes valores:

```
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|tag_html|tag_css|tag_javascript|count|
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|     0.0|    0.0|           0.0| 8655|
|     1.0|    0.0|           0.0|  141|
|     0.0|    0.0|           1.0|  782|
|     1.0|    0.0|           1.0|  107|
|     0.0|    1.0|           0.0|   96|
|     0.0|    1.0|           1.0|   20|
|     1.0|    1.0|           1.0|   46|
|     1.0|    1.0|           0.0|  153|
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
```

Ahora quiero guardar los valores de la columna `count` donde solo exista un '1' en toda la fila del DataFrame, por ejemplo se guardarían solo estos valores:

```
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|tag_html|tag_css|tag_javascript|count|
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|     1.0|    0.0|           0.0|  141|
|     0.0|    0.0|           1.0|  782|
|     0.0|    1.0|           0.0|   96|
```

Lo que he hecho fue usar la función `where()`

```
df['count'].where(((asdf['tag_html'] == 1) | (asdf['tag_css'] == 0) | (asdf['tag_javascript'] == 0)) & 
               ((asdf['tag_html'] == 0) | (asdf['tag_css'] == 1) | (asdf['tag_javascript'] == 0)) &
               ((asdf['tag_html'] == 0) | (asdf['tag_css'] == 0) | (asdf['tag_javascript'] == 1)))
```

y obtengo algo así:

```
0    8655.0
1     141.0
2     782.0
3       NaN
4      96.0
5       NaN
6      46.0
7       NaN
```

¿Hay alguna forma de realizar esta operación de una forma mejor? Me es indiferente si es en Pandas o PySpark.

Comment: Si tienes otra duda entonces crea una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la salida que dices esperar tienes un error en lógica del filtro, en el orden de los `and` y `or`. Esto ocasiona que también se validen las filas con todos los valores 1.0 y aquellas con todos los valores 0.0.

Debería ser así:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   tag_html  tag_css  tag_javascript  count
0       0.0      0.0             0.0   8655
1       1.0      0.0             0.0    141
2       0.0      0.0             1.0    782
3       1.0      0.0             1.0    107
4       0.0      1.0             0.0     96
5       0.0      1.0             1.0     20
6       1.0      1.0             1.0     46
7       1.0      1.0             0.0    153

In [3]: df[((df['tag_html'] == 1) & (df['tag_css'] == 0) & (df['tag_javascript'] == 0)) |
           ((df['tag_html'] == 0) & (df['tag_css'] == 1) & (df['tag_javascript'] == 0)) |
           ((df['tag_html'] == 0) & (df['tag_css'] == 0) & (df['tag_javascript'] == 1))]
Out[3]: 
   tag_html  tag_css  tag_javascript  count
1       1.0      0.0             0.0    141
2       0.0      0.0             1.0    782
4       0.0      1.0             0.0     96
```

En Pandas existe otra forma de hacer esto usando [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) junto a `sum`:

```
In [4]: df[df[['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].eq(1.0).sum(axis = 1) == 1]
Out[4]: 
   tag_html  tag_css  tag_javascript  count
1       1.0      0.0             0.0    141
2       0.0      0.0             1.0    782
4       0.0      1.0             0.0     96
```

Si sabes que tus columnas objetivo solo contienen 0 ó 1 estrictamente (y no otros valores como 1.002, 3, -1, etc) puedes usar `sum` directamente:

```
df[df[['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].sum(axis = 1) == 1]
```

Puedes usar `where` si quieres filtrar una columna como muestras en el ejemplo:

```
In[7]: df["count"].where(df[['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].eq(1).sum(axis = 1) == 1)
Out[7]: 
0      NaN
1    141.0
2    782.0
3      NaN
4     96.0
5      NaN
6      NaN
7      NaN
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

Un pequeño análisis de rendimiento de ambos métodos:

```
In [5]: %timeit df[((df['tag_html'] == 1) & (df['tag_css'] == 0) & (df['tag_javascript'] == 0)) | \
                   ((df['tag_html'] == 0) & (df['tag_css'] == 1) & (df['tag_javascript'] == 0)) | \
                   ((df['tag_html'] == 0) & (df['tag_css'] == 0) & (df['tag_javascript'] == 1))]
1000 loops, best of 3: 3.49 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit df[df[['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].eq(1).sum(axis = 1) == 1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop
```

No obstante dependerá de la extensión del DataFrame ya que esta tendencia es posible que se invierta en DataFrames con una cantidad relativamente grande de filas.

Comment: @FJSeviila hice la prueba con un dataframe mayor y el resultado es muy bueno. La funcion 'eq()' serviria en el caso de querer relacionar  la 'columna['count']'  con el nombre de la columna donde se encuentra solo se encuentra "1"?. Edito

Comment: ¿@EduardoCruz a que te refieres con relacionar la columna?¿Obtener otra columna que muestre el nombre de la columna en la que existe el 1.0?

Comment: Algo parecido, acabo de editar @FJSevilla