# Obtener nueva columna con el nombre de la columna que cumple cierta condición

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

A partir de un DataFrame de la forma:

```
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|tag_html|tag_css|tag_javascript|count|
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|     0.0|    0.0|           0.0| 8655|
|     1.0|    0.0|           0.0|  141|
|     0.0|    0.0|           1.0|  782|
|     1.0|    0.0|           1.0|  107|
|     0.0|    1.0|           0.0|   96|
|     0.0|    1.0|           1.0|   20|
|     1.0|    1.0|           1.0|   46|
|     1.0|    1.0|           0.0|  153|
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
```

Filtro aquellas filas que solo contiene un 1 en el conjunto de las columnas `tag_html|tag_css|tag_javascript` (Ver [¿Cómo filtrar filas que solo contienen un valor igual a 1?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/123684/15089)). Obteniendo un DataFrame como este:

```
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|tag_html|tag_css|tag_javascript|count|
+--------+-------+--------------+-----+
|     1.0|    0.0|           0.0|  141|
|     0.0|    0.0|           1.0|  782|
|     0.0|    1.0|           0.0|   96|
```

¿Cómo podría crear un nuevo DataFrame relacionando el valor de la columna `count` con el nombre de la columna donde solo aparece 1 de esa misma fila?

```
    +--------------------+
    |           tag|count|
    +--------+-----+-----+
    |      tag_html|  141|
    |tag_javascript|  782|
    |       tag_css|   96|
    +--------------+-----+
```

o bien solo guardar el valor en base a una lista.

Comment: @FJSevilla Así es como lo había editado anteriormente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción muy simple, dado que **tienes asegurado que solo tienes una columna con valor 1** (aparte de `count` obviamente) por el filtro previo, puedes usar [`pandas.DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) para obtener el nombre de la columna que contiene dicho valor:

```
df["Tag"] = df[['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].idxmax(axis = 1)
```

Partiendo de tu DataFrame original puedes hacer algo así:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

        df = pd.DataFrame({"tag_html": [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                           "tag_css": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                           "tag_javascript": [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                           "count": [8655, 141, 782, 107, 96, 20, 46, 153] 
                           },  columns = ["tag_html", "tag_css",
                                          "tag_javascript", "count"]
                          ) 

In [2]: mask = df[['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].eq(1).sum(axis = 1) == 1

In [3]: df["tag"] = df[mask][['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].idxmax(axis = 1)

In [4]: df[mask][["count", "tag"]]
Out[4]: 

   count             tag
1    141        tag_html
2    782  tag_javascript
4     96         tag_css
```

Si en vez de una vista quieres un DataFrame distinto simplemente usa 
`ctags = df[mask][["count", "tag"]].copy()`

---

**Edición:**

Añado una explicación más extendida de las dos lineas fundamentales del código anterior:

- `mask = df[['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].eq(1).sum(axis = 1) == 1`

  - `df[['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].eq(1)` simplemente itera sobre cada uno de los valores de las columnas seleccionadas comprobando que valores son iguales a 1, es decir, obtenemos:

    ```
       tag_html  tag_css  tag_javascript
    0     False    False           False
    1      True    False           False
    2     False    False            True
    3      True    False            True
    4     False     True           False
    5     False     True            True
    6      True     True            True
    7      True     True           False
    ```

    Si estamos seguros de que el DataFrame solo contiene 1 ó 0 en estas columnas, este paso no es necesario. Se puede aplicar `sum` directamente.
  - Con `.sum(axis = 1) == 1` creamos una mascara boleana que solo validará las filas en las que el número de valores `True` sean 1. Recordar que `False/True` son en esencia `0/1`, por lo que `sum([True, False, True])` es 2.). Con ello obtenemos la siguiente máscara:

    ```
    0    False
    1     True
    2     True
    3    False
    4     True
    5    False
    6    False
    7    False
    dtype: bool
    ```

    Esta máscara puede ser aplicada sobre `df` para obtener las filas que solo contienen un 1:

    ```
    In[1] : df[mask]
    Out[1]: 

       tag_html  tag_css  tag_javascript  count
    1       1.0      0.0             0.0    141
    2       0.0      0.0             1.0    782
    4       0.0      1.0             0.0     96
    ```
- `df["tag"] = df[mask][['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].idxmax(axis = 1)`: Creamos una nueva columna en el DataFrame (`df["tag"]`) con los valores retornados por `idxmax` al ser aplicado sobre las filas que solo tienen un 1 (`df[mask]`) y sobre las tres columnas que nos interesan (`[['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']]`). Al indicar `axis = 1` hacemos que se aplique sobre las filas. `idxmax` retorna el índice `(axis = 0)` o columna `(axis = 1)` que tiene el valor máximo. Como sabemos seguro que solo hay un 1 entre los valores, siempre obtendremos la columna propietaria del 1 ya que es el valor máximo de los tres. En definitiva obtenemos:

  ```
  In[2] : df[mask][['tag_html', 'tag_css', 'tag_javascript']].idxmax(axis = 1)
  Out[3]: 

  1          tag_html
  2    tag_javascript
  4           tag_css
  dtype: object
  ```

Comment: Podrías por favor profundizar un poco que esta pasando en `In [2]` e `In[3]`. Quiero entender mejor el concepto.

Comment: @JavierCárdenas he editado la pregunta añadiendo una pequeña explicación al final, no se si habrá quedado medianamente claro.